# Find physical computer user name from within MSTSC

Tags: batch-file, remote-access, terminal-services, mstsc

So here's the dealio. I would like to create a simple batch file that'll create a log of each user that remotes in to a server. I know I can use

```
echo %username% > lastuser.log
```

but we all use the same username to log in to the server. I was wondering if it was possible to replace the "%username%" with some variable that'll return the physical computer that MSTSC is running on's name. I'd also like this to be a running list with the time of log in, but I can probably figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for %CLIENTNAME%.

Comment: Side challenge. How do I make it so it echo's a new entry in to the log file rather than overwriting it?

Comment: You'd want to use the >> operator, as in `echo %CLIENTNAME% >> lastuser.log`. See the list of [command redirection operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want to do this on the server machine.  I don't have MSTSC running at the moment, so I can't check this exactly, but suppose when a user logs in, the server does a `netstat` to see which remote machines have connections using the server on the MSTSC port.  Would that work?

Comment: Hrm, this didn't return anything.

'echo %netstat%' just returns 'netstat'

Comment: @Jared, netstat is a command.  at the command prompt, just type `netstat`.  `netstat /?` shows the command usage.